# Translate checkout strings

Tags: magento2, localisation

I want to transalte several strings in the checkout, however, putting them in a CSV or turining on inline translation doesn't seem to rename them.

[image]

How can I rename `Shipping`, `Review & Payments` and `Please enter a valid email address (Ex: johndoe@domain.com).`?

Comment: What language pack are you using? Do you find "Shipping" and "Review & Payments" inside your language pack?
On Magento 2.1.3 for JS message error translation I'm using validation.js from develop branch, I've develop an extension to extend Magento core for this.

Comment: As written in der question itself it does not matter if I put the content into the CSV or not, it simply does not translate. As for the validation.js, could you elaborate here? Sounds useful!

Answer (score 1):

**In order to override JS validation class you need to create a new module**

**app/code/local/Vendor/OverrideCore/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_OverrideCore" setup_version="0.1.0" />
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Vendor/OverrideCore/composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "vendor/overridecore",
  "description": "Override Core for Magento 2",
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Vendor",
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Vendor\\OverrideCore\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

**app/code/local/Vendor/OverrideCore/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_OverrideCore',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Inside your new module create those folders:**

`app/code/local/Vendor/OverrideCore/view/frontend/web/`
`app/code/local/Vendor/OverrideCore/view/frontend/web/js/`

**Create this file `app/code/local/Vendor/OverrideCore/view/frontend/web/requirejs-config.js`:**

```
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
/*global alert*/
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'mage/validation': 'Vendor_OverrideCore/js/validation',
            'mage/validation/validation': 'Vendor_OverrideCore/js/validation',
            passwordStrengthIndicator : 'Vendor_OverrideCore/js/password-strength-indicator'
        }
    }
};
```

**Create this file `app/code/local/Vendor/OverrideCore/view/frontend/web/js/password-strength-indicator.js`:**

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/web/js/password-strength-indicator.js

**Create this file `app/code/local/Vendor/OverrideCore/view/frontend/web/js/validation.js`:**

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/web/mage/validation/validation.js

**Enable module**

`php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_OverrideCore`

Comment: How'd you replace the `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js`-file? Could you make an example, please?

Comment: `var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': 'Vendor_OverrideCore/js/view/shipping'
        }
    }
};`

Comment: Your solution breaks the checkout anyhow in Magento 2.0.9. :(

Comment: Sorry as I told you this solution is working on 2.1.3 CE. Do a diff between this files and your version, you will see that's a lot about translate method calls missing.

Comment: I thank you anyway for your effort to help me! :-* Appreciated, even if not functional... Those Mage devs... u.u

Comment: You welcome :) Do a diff between these files from develop branch and your files version 2.0.9, you will see that's a lot about translate method calls missing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a module, maybe you can translate this files in your theme folder.

To solve this Magento bug, i copy the file lib/web/mage/validation.js to my theme and translated it there.

So, the translated file is in: app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/mage/validation.js

Make sure to: rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* and rm -rf pub/static/* and refresh !